# Is there a way to search for which models I can play in which Warhammer army?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Say I wanted to field an Inquisition army with Grey Knights and... Lets say Astropaths. I want to do that because I've read some of the lore, and I want a fluffy army, not strictly an optimised army.

Or maybe I found Vespid, and I want to know what army they are meant to be played with?

Is there a way to search for keywords by model name, or the reverse, all models that have a keyword?

This is important as keywords are how you determine [which models can synergise in a detachment](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/8460/2133), with [some exceptions](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/53847/2133).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visit the GW site like the answer above. To see rules and in which army you can play which unit you can also visit Wahapedia before investing in a Codex of the army to be sure it is what you like.

Next to that you have listbuilder apps. When choosing a army, you can choose every unit that can be in that army. Games Workshop recently launched their own, but most of it is paid. An alternative, free and established app is Battlescribe. It can be a little bit hard to set up if your not into computers, like some of my friends say. (it can be used for more games, so you have to establish a Database) But when ready its perfect for list building and seeing rules that belongs to the units chosen.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer is to use the gamesworkshop website and filter by the army you want, eg going to https://www.games-workshop.com/en-AU/Warhammer-40-000 and scrolling down, looking on the left for space marines, then ticking the grey knights box. I don't think that actually shows all of them though (or perhaps grey knights can't get assassins anymore?).